# Unity - make object face the same direction on one axis? Not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Ok, I have the Main Camera able to turn on all 4 axes using Google's Magic Window script and the iPhone gyro. I also have a character that exists on the ground and needs to face the same direction as the player, meaning where they are looking.

From what I can see this is the y axis:

[image]
Neither objects are children of anything. Issue is when I do this to align the character with the y axis of the Camera (the player):

```
 transform.rotation = new Quaternion(transform.rotation.x, player.transform.rotation.y, transform.rotation.z, transform.rotation.w);
```

I get nothing. Ive tried other axes but y is supposed to be left/right, and I don't understand whats wrong here.

Do I need to do something with transform.forward? Whats the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best solution but you could use `transform.forward`, as you mentioned, remove the Y component and transform it into a Quaternion.

```
Vector3 rotation = camera.transform.forward;
rotation.y = 0f;

player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rotation);
```